# Perpendicular surfaces

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

I have the surfaces $$ x^2 +y^2 -z^2 = 1 $$ $$ x^2+cy^2+2z^2=1$$ and I need to determine for wich none negative vaules of **c** there exist intersection point and their are perpendicular each other there.

So what I did is to find the gradients of the two surfaces and make sure they are perpendicular each other because it will promise me that their tangent planes are also perpendicular each other, so I wrote

$$(2x,2y,-2z)\cdot(2x,2cy,4z)=0 \hspace{2mm}\Longrightarrow 4x^2+4cy^2-8z^2=0 \hspace{2mm}\Longrightarrow x^2+cy^2=2z^2$$   from here I am not sure how  should I continue. I would like for an explanation what I should do and what is the reason for doing that.

thank you kindly.

Comment: Start with the first part of the task.

Comment: thats what I did, I did dot product between the gradients

Comment: Hint: Subtract both equations to derive $c<1$.

Comment: Yes this is what you did but I suggest you to start with exploring the intersection issue and estimation of $c $.